# Double and single quotes in JS inside HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onload="test();">

  <script>
    var number=1;
    var input='<div><input type="text"><div>'+
    '<div>'+number+'</div>'+ 
    '<input type="text">';

    function test(){
      var div = document.getElementById('result');
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input;
    }

  </script>
  <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with code above? For some reason my first input box has size of 100 even should be 1.

Comment: Anything inside <? is going to be php executed, you won't be able to throw javascript inside of that if that's what your trying to do.

Comment: How about indenting your code properly to increase its readability? I'm sure you'll spot the issue right on …

Comment: `<? if(1==1){ ?>` Seriously??

Comment: @faridv I'm assuming `number` is going to be dynamic.

Comment: But if `number` is intended to be a javascript variable, then it won't work that way since php will execute before the javascript will.

Comment: @Caimen is right.  Javascript is client side.  PHP is server side.  You can't pass data between the client and the server unless you perform an HTTP request.

Comment: In this case, you really don't need to be using PHP.  The conditional logic your performing can be done with javascript as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access JavaScript variables like `number` in `php`.

If you want to use `number` you need to do it in `JavaScript` like this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="test();">
    <script>
        var number = 1;
        var input = '<div><input type="text";';
        input += number == 1 ? ' size="1" ' : ' size="100" ';
        input += '><div>';
        input += '<div>' + number + '</div>';
        input += '<input type="text" ';
        input += 1 == 1 ? ' size="1" ' : ' size="100" ';
        input += '>';

        function test() {
            var div = document.getElementById('result');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + input;
        }
    </script>
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because php code is executed before js code. While php is executed it tries to check '+number+' is 1 which it is not. It is a string.

Php code is executed in server and js code in browser. That is huge difference.